# Do I have to repeat my previous calculations after increasing 'diago_david_ndir' in the input file of the bandstructure calculations?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, physical-properties-of-materials, density-of-states

After doing the convergence test, 'vc-relax' and 'scf' calculations for my material using Quantum ESPRESSO everything went well. But when I wanted to do a 'bands' calculation for bandstructure I got the message `Error in routine cdiaghg (283):S matrix not positive definite`  in the output file.
So I increased 'diago_david_ndir' to '4', the default was '2'.And the problem was fixed. But I'm just wondering if I have to repeat the whole calculations from the beginning with diago_david_ndir=4 ( Convergence test, vc-relax, scf) then perform the 'bands' calculations.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?